# ORMLite and Oracle - case sensitive column names

Tags: oracle, ormlite

I have just started using ORMLite and was using at home to experiment on MySQL. Now I have decided to try using it on Oracle, but have noticed an issue with case sensitivity of column names.

When using the `TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists()` it appears to generate CREATE statements that wrap the table and column names in double quotes. For example:

> CREATE TABLE "T_SUBURB" ("id" NUMERIC , "description" VARCHAR2(255)
>   NOT NULL , "gnaf" VARCHAR2(255) , PRIMARY KEY ("id") )

This means that when I am attempting to query the database in Oracle SQL Developer I have to use the double quotes to specify the table and column names. This doesn't seem to happen when using MySQL.

I must admit I am a SQL novice, however it doesn't seem natural to wrap every table or column name in double quotes when attempting to query them. Looking at the OracleDatabaseType implementation it would seem that the entity name is intentionally double quoted in this example.

Does anybody know of a way to turn this behaviour off?

I am currently running version 4.43 from maven-central and Oracle 11g.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists() it appears to generate CREATE statements that wrap the table and column names in double quotes.

That's correct.  The challenge for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is that it has to protect against special characters or reserved-words as field and table names.  Words like `"index"` or `"create"` might make fine field names but will cause invalid SQL.

However, according to my reading of the `OracleDatabaseType` is should be generating *uppercase* field names:

```
@Override
public boolean isEntityNamesMustBeUpCase() {
    return true;
}
```

If your field is created as `"description"` then something is wrong.  Does `DESCRIPTION` work instead?  Is ORMLite generating your schema and using an Oracle JDBC URI?  Something like:

```
jdbc:oracle:...
```

If you are not using a JDBC URI like that then ORMLite may not be using the Oracle database type to create your tables.  If you need to *force* it to use Oracle, you can create your

```
ConnectionSource connectionSource =
    new JdbcConnectionSource(databaseUrl, new OracleDatabaseType());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gray,


Thankyou for your answer, you are correct - the table names are in uppercase, I was just writing the example from memory.


I take your comment about creating invalid SQL, however ORMLite is the first ORM I've seen that doesn't either fail at creation because a reserved word is used, or just fail when attempting to use the SQL.


I am wondering if there could be an option that allows me to specify whether escaping of names should be used or not (default to true to  be backwards compatible). That way the developer can choose whether they want this functionality or not.

Comment: I assure you that hibernate and other modern ORMs do the same escaping.  Is the problem that you don't want to use uppercase or am I missing something @Aidos?